# Yikes!!! Restore windows.old folder after being deleted?

Tags: windows, windows-7-restore

Basically, I used Disk Cleanup utility on a windows 7 Ultimate machine to delete the Windows.old folder only to discover that it contained a critical amount of data in the 'users/JonDoe/' which was referenced to from the upgrade by a simple shortcut on the desktop. How can I recover the windows.old folder in windows 7 ultimate after it has been deleted? I know that there are thousands of 'un-delete' programs out there, but which one is free, no limitations in trial and highly recommended? Does Microsoft have a utility to undo? Ive looked but can't seem to find anything, please help.

Comment: One of the reasons besides the fact its a duplicate of an already existing thread we really don't do software suggestion.  Since you seem to be aware there are lots of recovery software choices you can select the one that best solves our problem.

Comment: Perhaps you may wish to add this as a solution to this existing problem then. 

SOLUTION:

"If you've got old system restore points available you can simply mount one then browse to your windows.old folder and copy it back to your current hard drive.

System Restore Point browser/ mounter can be found here: http://nicbedford.co.uk/software/systemrestoreexplorer/
Direct dowload link for installer: nicbedford.co.uk/files/InstallSys… 

Don't forget to dismount afterwards."

PS.  I noticed links are cut short, so the program/utility is called System Restore Explorer on the above links.

Comment: I don't make a habit of posting other people's answers to problems.  You should post your comment as a possible answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Pirisoft Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), which is free. Be aware that to have a chance at recovering the files you should avoid writing to disk or using other programs, as the files that they create might overwrite the data that you deleted. You should also put Recuva on a USB drive (from another computer).